# Acces SQLite database with C++ on iOS?

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios, sqlite

Is it possible to acces the SQLite API on iOS using C++ instead of Objective-C? I'm working on a music sequencer and I think my best option is storing the notes in a SQLite database with an indexed measure column.

I need those notes to calculate my sound frames and C++ is recommended for real time audio processing. (I'm calculating the sine wave for each note.) I'm guessing that using C++ for the SQLite database would speed things up as well and that way I wouldn't have to switch from Obj-C to C++ all the time.

Any idea if this is possible, and any examples?

Comment: Just rename your .m files to .mm and you can use C++ in your project as normal! (ObjC++ ftw)

Comment: The SQLite API is written in C.  All you have to do is call it.  Nothing special about using Objective-C.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Any time you use a database, it's going to be much, much slower than the few cycles it might cost to call an Obj-C function from C++.

This is a premature optimization. Just access the database the easy way, and **if** and when it ever becomes a problem, you'll be in a much better position to fix it, because by then you'll know *where* the bottleneck is.

Comment: I don't think you read the question properly - he's ALREADY in c++ and wants to avoid having to shuffle from C++ to Objective-C just to use the database.

Comment: @AndyDent: no, I did read the question. My point is that performance-wise (which is what the OP seems concerned about), it won't make a difference if you have to call into Obj-C code every time you access the database, because database access is already orders of magnitude slower than that. So sure, being able to access the database from C++ is convenient, but performance-wise, it is not necessary.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is possible. You just need to add SQLite library to your project, and follow the [SQLite C/C++ API](http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html).